# Filter one JSON from another JSON in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In Angular, I have two JSONs, one JSON(A) consist of entire vehicle records whereas other JSON (B) consist of ids. I want to return only match ids records from JSON (A). Below are details

**JSON (A)**

```
{
         "id":100,
         "brand":"Tes1",
         "vname":"Testname1",
 },
 {
         "id":200,
         "brand":"Tes2",
         "vname":"Testname2",
 },
{
         "id":300,
         "brand":"Tes3",
         "vname":"Testname3",
 }
```

**JSON (B)**

```
{
         "id":100
 },
{
         "id":300
 },
```

**Expected Output after aaply filter to (A) by (B)**

```
{
         "id":100,
         "brand":"Tes1",
         "vname":"Testname1",
 },
{
         "id":300,
         "brand":"Tes3",
         "vname":"Testname3",
 },
```

Comment: Can you show code related to rxjs?

Comment: Could you add some trial code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Array.prorotype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combined with [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Code:

```js
const jsonA = [{id: 100,brand: 'Tes1',vname: 'Testname1',},{id: 200,brand: 'Tes2',vname: 'Testname2',},{id: 300,brand: 'Tes3',vname: 'Testname3',},]

const jsonB = [
  {
    id: 100,
  },
  {
    id: 300,
  },
]

const filteredData = jsonA.filter((itemA) => jsonB.some((itemB) => itemB.id === itemA.id))

console.log(filteredData)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are conserned about performance then `filter`&`some` can impact your app as it contains nested loops. In that case you can rely on lookup

```js
const jsonA = [{id: 100,brand: 'Tes1',vname: 'Testname1',}, {id: 200,brand: 'Tes2',vname: 'Testname2',}, {id: 300,brand: 'Tes3',vname: 'Testname3',}]

const jsonB = [{id: 100}, {id: 300}]

const map = new Map(jsonB.map(obj => [obj.id, obj]));
const intersection = jsonA.filter(obj => map.has(obj.id));

console.log(intersection);
```